# how to create a measure that filters 2 tables

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have the following two tables in power bi that share a many to many relationship.

Table1

```
code | Name | QuestionID
11   | Test |123
12   | Test |123
```

Table 2

```
Code | Name | Answer | Compliant| QuestionID
11   |Test  | Yes    | 1        |123
12   |Test  | Yes    | 1        |123
458  |Test2 | NO     | 0        |256
678  |Test3 | Yes    | 0        |000
```

So as you can see in table 1 there is a QuestionId and code and in Table 2 their is also a matching QuestionID and code

I want to count only one answer for the questionID from Table2 where the question ID and code exists in Table 1

As you can see theirs two question answered for QuestionID 123 but i only want to take it as a count of one answer.(note their can be multiple answers for the same question)

I don't know how to filter the two tables.

This is what I tried

```
Measure =
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( 'Table 2'[Answer] ),
    FILTER ( 'Table1', 'Table1'[Code] = 'Table 2'[code] )
        && 'Table 2'[Compliant] = 1
)
```

but this doesn't work cause on the FILTER when joining table 2 it breaks because it doesn't like the second table.

Comment: What column is the relationship on and what direction is the filtering? Where are you using the measure? If it's in a visual, what table columns are you using for which fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't expect a Table 2 column reference like that since columns generally have more than one row. This might work instead:

```
Measure =
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( 'Table 2'[Answer] ),
    FILTER (
        'Table 2',
        'Table 2'[Code] IN VALUES ( 'Table1'[code] )
            && 'Table 2'[Compliant] = 1
    )
) + 0
```

The relationship should handle the filtering of Table1 on Table2 though. So you should be able to write it more simply by applying Table1 as a filtering table like this:

```
Measure =
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( 'Table 2'[Answer] ),
    'Table1',
    FILTER ( 'Table 2', 'Table 2'[Compliant] = 1 )
) + 0
```

(In both cases, the `+ 0` is to return a zero instead of a blank. You can remove that if you prefer a blank instead.)

Comment: My table relationship changed from 1 to many to, many to many now... Is their a way I can filter on the code as you showed me above with two columns from table 1 matching table 2, so that I can count only one answer associated to multiple same codes

Comment: What is the condition you want to match on, exactly?

Comment: i have an additional column now ,callled questionID, so i want to check from table 2 if the code and the questionID matches the code and questionID in table one, then only count 1 answer

Comment: Try changing `&&` to a comma. You are ANDing a table with a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly your question translates to something like this: **I want to count all distinct Question ID that exist on both tables.**

Therefore try this measure

```
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(Table2[questionId]),  
    FILTER(
        Table2,
        RELATED(Table1[questionId])
    )
)
```

A litle off topic but i advise againts using many to many relationship between tables even on power bi.